# Cloudstack: Failed to attach volume Data to VM Nas12U41

Tags: volume, nas, apache-cloudstack

Failed to attach volume **Data** to VM **Nas12U41**; org.libvirt.LibvirtException: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command '__com.redhat_drive_add': could not open disk image /mnt/3c164f13-17f2-3edf-b836-74299f20a559/65bcbd35-4fc5-4714-af04-4712a6a7f0e7: qcow2: Image is corrupt; cannot be opened read/write

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check if the storage is healthy, and the file exists and is healthy. Depending on what filesystem and primary storage you're using you may run fsck or equivalent to recover the corrupted file. You may also want to check file permissions. Can you share your CloudStack version, output of "virsh version", "qemu-img info" on the qcow2 file and KVM host distro.

To discuss further pl join the CloudStack users mailing list and ask there http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).